# Hibernate saveorupdateall not doing save not update

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a spring integration hibernate application. My application picks up files and checks their entries against the database. For this i am using Hibernate.

I want to disable certain rows in the database. I am retrieving the rows using criteria. Editing one field and using saveorupdateall method. This is not changing my db rows at all!!

Following are the code snippets

```
  <bean id="dmsdbDetectionJob" class="com.polling.scheduler.job.DMSDBDetectionJob">

 </bean>
 <bean id="dmsdbDetectionJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="dmsdbDetectionJob" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="deleteDBMaster" />
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
 </bean>
<bean id="simpleTriggerDB" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="dmsdbDetectionJobDetail" />
    <!-- <property name="cronExpression" value="1 * * * * ?" /> --> 
<!--    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/1 * * * ?" />  -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 52 11 ? * *" />
 </bean>
```

This fires at given time properly. deleteDBMaster method calls this code:

```
        //get Document files not having any links
        List<DocumentFile> strayFiles = documentDaoImpl.getStrayDocumentFiles();
        try
        {
            if (strayFiles.size() > 0)
            {
                //delete
                strayFiles = documentDaoImpl.softDelete(strayFiles, DocumentFile.class);
                documentDaoImpl.saveOrUpdateAll(strayFiles);}
}...
```

The softDelete method uses generics

```
    @Override
public <T extends GenericEntity> List<T> softDelete(List<T> stray,
        Class<T> clazz)
{
    for (T tObj : stray)
    {
        clazz.cast(tObj).setActive(Constants.INACTIVE.getVal());

    }
    return stray;
}
```

When I debug I see the value changed in the active property of the objects in the strayFiles list, inside saveOrUpdateAll() method. The saveOrUpdateAll method is:

```
@Override
public void saveOrUpdateAll(Collection<?> objects) throws DMSException  {
    try {
        for (Object object : objects) {
            getCrntSession().saveOrUpdate(object);
        }
    } catch (final HibernateException e) {
        throw new DMSException("Exception while save or update All ", ErrorCode.BASE_DB_ERROR, e);
    }
}
```

When the saveorupdate is called no query is logged by hibernate. Nothing changes in the db!!

Since this is in spring integration I have just added a @Transactional to the method. I am presuming that spring must do the flush or commit. Is that wrong? And even then I should see the query right??

Please let me know what is wrong in the code...

Thanks

EDIT::

Change my softdelete code to the following. Thought maybe the generics are causing this.

```
    @Override
@Transactional
public void softDeleteDocumentFile(
        List<DocumentFile> stray)
{
    for (DocumentFile tObj : stray)
    {
        tObj.setActive(Constants.INACTIVE.getVal());
        saveEntity(tObj);
    }
}
```

Still no change. The rows are not getting updated. Hibernate is not printing the update query on the console!!

Please let me know if anyone finds any mistake in the code..

EDIT::

This is the configuration

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.polling" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
     <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/jdbc.properties,classpath:config/config.properties,classpath:config/ftp.properties"/>
      <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        </bean>
      <!-- Configure Hibernate 4 Session Factory -->
      <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

            <property name="dataSource">
                  <ref bean="dataSource" />
            </property>

            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                  <props>
                        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
                  </props>
            </property>
            <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.polling.entity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
            </bean>
            <tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

EDIT::

Tried using a hardcoded id. Used update instead of save. But still same result, no update query and hence no change in row!!

EDIT::
This is the log at trace level

```
    14:31:12.644 T|TransactionInterceptor                  |Completing transaction for [com.polling.service.DocumentServiceImpl.deActivateStrays]
14:31:12.644 T|TransactionInterceptor                  |Completing transaction for [com.polling.scheduler.job.DMSDBDetectionJob.deleteDBMaster]
14:31:12.675 T|HibernateTransactionManager             |Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
14:31:12.675 T|HibernateTransactionManager             |Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
14:31:12.675 D|HibernateTransactionManager             |Initiating transaction commit
14:31:12.675 D|HibernateTransactionManager             |Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.polling.entity.DocumentFile#273], EntityKey[com.polling.entity.DocumentGroup#107], EntityKey[com.polling.entity.DocumentFile#275]],collectionKeys=[CollectionKey[com.polling.entity.DocumentFile.docgroups#275], CollectionKey[com.polling.entity.DocumentGroup.files#107], CollectionKey[com.polling.entity.DocumentFile.docgroups#273]]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2a6f7180 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7a84a043 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1935cd8c orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1b49af42 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@291240d collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6d5d2cc collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@40025295 collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@587bd507 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
14:31:12.675 D|AbstractTransactionImpl                 |committing
14:31:12.675 T|SessionImpl                             |Automatically flushing session
14:31:12.675 T|AbstractFlushingEventListener           |Flushing session
14:31:12.675 D|AbstractFlushingEventListener           |Processing flush-time cascades
14:31:12.675 T|Cascade                                 |Processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: com.polling.entity.DocumentFile
14:31:12.675 T|Cascade                                 |Done processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: com.polling.entity.DocumentFile
14:31:12.675 T|Cascade                                 |Processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: com.polling.entity.DocumentFile
14:31:12.675 T|Cascade                                 |Done processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: com.polling.entity.DocumentFile
14:31:12.675 D|AbstractFlushingEventListener           |Dirty checking collections
14:31:12.675 T|AbstractFlushingEventListener           |Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
14:31:12.675 D|Collections                             |Collection found: [com.polling.entity.DocumentFile.docgroups#273], was: [com.polling.entity.DocumentFile.docgroups#273] (uninitialized)
14:31:12.691 D|Collections                             |Collection found: [com.polling.entity.DocumentFile.docgroups#275], was: [com.polling.entity.DocumentFile.docgroups#275] (uninitialized)
14:31:12.691 D|Collections                             |Collection found: [com.polling.entity.DocumentGroup.files#107], was: [com.polling.entity.DocumentGroup.files#107] (uninitialized)
14:31:12.691 T|AbstractFlushingEventListener           |Processing unreferenced collections
14:31:12.691 T|AbstractFlushingEventListener           |Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
14:31:12.691 D|AbstractFlushingEventListener           |Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 3 objects
14:31:12.691 D|AbstractFlushingEventListener           |Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 3 collections
14:31:12.691 D|EntityPrinter                           |Listing entities:
14:31:12.691 D|EntityPrinter                           |com.polling.entity.DocumentFile{encodingKey=yyy, docgroups=<uninitialized>, contactNumber=12121212, documentType=com.polling.entity.DocumentType#5, totalLinks=1, modifiedBy=com.polling.entity.UserApplicationGroup#3, documentFileName=f11, documentDescription=null, totalDownloads=0, uploaderCompletePath=somepath/somepath, modifiedDate=2014-12-16 14:36:57.707, size=0, DMSPath=c:/DMSFinalRoot\dir0\File0, id=273, createdBy=com.polling.entity.UserApplicationGroup#3, documentFormat=com.polling.entity.DocumentFormat#1, uploadDateTime=2014-12-16 14:36:56.86, keyWords=null, active=3, uploadStage=1, uploaderIP=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, createdDate=2014-12-16 14:36:57.707, contactPerson=some name, uploaderName=scmsname}
14:31:12.691 D|EntityPrinter                           |com.polling.entity.DocumentGroup{files=<uninitialized>, expiryPresent=false, modifiedBy=com.polling.entity.UserApplicationGroup#3, uploadStatus=0, documentDescription=null, modifiedDate=2014-12-22 14:28:09.027, id=107, nodeId=206, totalFiles=0, createdBy=com.polling.entity.UserApplicationGroup#3, documentFormat=null, objectId=101, active=3, documentName=doc1, nodeType=document, objectType=demand, createdDate=2014-12-22 14:28:09.027, expiryAt=null}
14:31:12.691 D|EntityPrinter                           |com.polling.entity.DocumentFile{encodingKey=azaz, docgroups=<uninitialized>, contactNumber=12121212, documentType=com.polling.entity.DocumentType#5, totalLinks=1, modifiedBy=com.polling.entity.UserApplicationGroup#3, documentFileName=f11, documentDescription=null, totalDownloads=0, uploaderCompletePath=somepath/somepath, modifiedDate=2014-12-17 16:52:23.163, size=0, DMSPath=c:/DMSFinalRoot\dir2\File0, id=275, createdBy=com.polling.entity.UserApplicationGroup#3, documentFormat=com.polling.entity.DocumentFormat#1, uploadDateTime=2014-12-17 16:52:22.127, keyWords=null, active=9, uploadStage=1, uploaderIP=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, createdDate=2014-12-17 16:52:23.163, contactPerson=some name, uploaderName=scmsname}
14:31:12.691 T|AbstractFlushingEventListener           |Executing flush
14:31:12.691 T|JdbcCoordinatorImpl                     |Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
14:31:12.691 T|AbstractFlushingEventListener           |Post flush
14:31:12.691 T|SessionImpl                             |before transaction completion
14:31:12.691 D|JdbcTransaction                         |committed JDBC Connection
14:31:12.691 D|JdbcTransaction                         |re-enabling autocommit
14:31:12.691 T|TransactionCoordinatorImpl              |after transaction completion
14:31:12.707 T|SessionImpl                             |after transaction completion
14:31:12.707 T|HibernateTransactionManager             |Triggering afterCommit synchronization
14:31:12.707 T|HibernateTransactionManager             |Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
14:31:12.707 T|TransactionSynchronizationManager       |Clearing transaction synchronization
14:31:12.707 T|TransactionSynchronizationManager       |Removed value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionHolder@711fbb66] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@5e2ed6a9] from thread [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-7]
14:31:12.707 T|TransactionSynchronizationManager       |Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@67914078] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@7bc247d0] from thread [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-7]
14:31:12.707 D|HibernateTransactionManager             |Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.polling.entity.DocumentFile#273], EntityKey[com.polling.entity.DocumentGroup#107], EntityKey[com.polling.entity.DocumentFile#275]],collectionKeys=[CollectionKey[com.polling.entity.DocumentFile.docgroups#275], CollectionKey[com.polling.entity.DocumentGroup.files#107], CollectionKey[com.polling.entity.DocumentFile.docgroups#273]]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2a6f7180 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7a84a043 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1935cd8c orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1b49af42 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@291240d collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6d5d2cc collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@40025295 collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@587bd507 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction
14:31:12.707 T|SessionImpl                             |Closing session
14:31:12.707 I|StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener  |Session Metrics {
    36322379 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    16153296 nanoseconds spent preparing 2 JDBC statements;
    20467177 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    7830765 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 3 entities and 3 collections);
    85953666 nanoseconds spent executing 2 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 2 entities and 2 collections)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear where there is Spring Integration. Share, please, your SI config on the matter.

Comment: the integration part is not relevant for this question. I can change the tag for the q. Cron tigger and poller are all that are used for this.

Comment: Had used javax transaction annotation in the code by mistake. Changed it to the spring annotation. But no effect!!!:(

Comment: Please provide spring application context configuration parts related to hibernate session factory, transactions, component scanning, dao beans wiring, ... .

Comment: From what you've written so far and in your comments it seems like a missing or wrong Spring TransactionManager / AOP Configuration. Can you please add your Spring TransactionManager / Datasource / AOP Configuration otherwise it's not possible to figure it out. You may also have a look at the Spring [Transaction Management Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Comment: Any Help is welcome!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have found the crux of my problem. Wasnt related to transactions at all. By mistake I had added updatable=false to my entity class property(active) get accessor. Sorry for the trouble. Really a very elementary mistake!!! Apologies to all that have spent time on this..

Answer (score 1):

session.saveOrUpdate(Object) method only converts any transient object into persistence object, means object associates with current hibernate session. When current hibernate session will be flushed or hibernate transaction will be committed then only actual query will run to store object data into the database.

Hibernate saveOrUpdate(Object) works like above comment. I don't know much about Spring.
I hope above description will work for you.

Example code : Hibernate

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.setFlush(FlushMode.COMMIT);// Session will be flushed when transation.commit will be called
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(Object obj);
tx.commit();// this line will run query to map your object on database

 OR

Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.setFlush(FlushMode.MANUAL);// Session will be only ever flushed when session.flush() will be explicitely called by aaplication
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(Object obj);
session.flush();// this line will run query to map your object on database
tx.commit();
```

Thanks

Comment: I added a getCrntSession().getTransaction().commit(); and got a transaction not started exception. Then changed it to a flush(). Exception went but no query and no change in db!!

Answer (score 1):

What you've written so far seems that your Spring TransactionManagement configuration is wrong.

A simple solution if you don't want to configure aspects is to use a programmatic approach using the Spring Framework `TransactionTemplate`

```
public class DMSDBDetectionJob {

    private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    public DMSDBDetectionJob(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
       Assert.notNull(transactionManager, "The 'transactionManager' argument must not be null.");
       this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
       // optional configuration of the Transaction like timeout
       // this.transactionTemplate.setTimeout(30); // 30 seconds
    }

    public void deleteDBMaster() {
      transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
          protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
             deleteDBMasterImpl();
         }
       });

    }

    private void deleteDBMasterImpl() {
        List<DocumentFile> strayFiles = documentDaoImpl.getStrayDocumentFiles();
        try
        {
           if (strayFiles.size() > 0)
           {
              //delete
              strayFiles = documentDaoImpl.softDelete(strayFiles, DocumentFile.class);
              documentDaoImpl.saveOrUpdateAll(strayFiles);
              ...
            }

         } catch (...) {...}
    }
```

Your Spring Configuration should have at least two entries like:

```
<!-- PlatformTransactionManager which are going to drive transaction-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Instance of transaction template -->
<bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
  <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: should I autowire the instance transactionTemplate. It needs to be initialised

Comment: Used @Autowire for the transactionTemplate and removed the final. No error but still no update query and no change in DB. I guess transactions is not the problem! Also used the org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager